# error code=13 when I run Aptana

Tags: java, aptana

I just downloaded the current version of the program on Windows 7 SP1 x64 system. It gave no indication of problems when installing.

It starts out "Java was started but returned exit code =13

I have no idea what this means or the rest of the apparent Java information.

Others seem to say it is a conflict in bit size 32 vs 64. The download said 64 bit compatible, so it should work on either. I need specific help here.

Comment: You say you need specific help, but you give very little specific information.  However, the linked Q&A (and others) most likely covers your situation.

Comment: I see that I am running Java jdk and jre 8u45 x64. When I look at C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath, each of the links target a 64 bit version of Java. I happen to also have Eclipse Luna (64 bit) running on this machine and it loads normally. I do see a statement in the returned error page  --launcher.library C:\Users\Neal\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212.eclipse_1503.dll Strange statement that seems to refer to both Aptana and Eclipse, but it does say 32. Is this somehow the culprit?

Comment: A basic question here is: Does the Aptana Studio 3 as downloaded for Windows actually work with a 64 bit Java? It Says, " Aptana Studio 3.6.1
Microsoft Windows, x86 (x64 Compatible) "

Comment: You appear to have download an x86 (32 bit) version.  That will run on Windows x86-64 (64 bit) ... but only if you use a 32 bit Java installation to run Eclipse.

Comment: Since I have 64 bit Java installed and am running Eclipse 64, can I also install the 32 bit Java? Will that screw up the previous installation? Or is there a 64 bit Aptana available?

Comment: You can have multiple Java installations on the same Windows machine.  The worst that can happen is that you will end up with the "wrong" one as the default, but I expect there is a way to remedy that.

Comment: *"Or is there a 64 bit Aptana available?"* - Can you find one?  If yes, then yes.  If no then (probably) no.  (Hint: click the "customize your download" button in the download page ...)

Comment: Solved by just installing 32 bit Java and it didn't mess up my 64 bit eclipse....thanks and PS: customization of Aptana download just means choosing op system and for Linux there is indeed a 64 bit version, but not for Windows or Mac. The wrods "64 bit compatible" are what threw me off.